# ElasticSearch Convert Rest Query TO Transport Client Java Code

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-aggregation

Thanks in Advance for Help,

I have created a elastic search _search query as below :

```
{
    "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "attrs_root": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "scope_term": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.scope.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "tag_term": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.tag.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to convert this query in Java Elastic Search Transport Client 6.2 . I tried with below code but it is not returning same results. :

```
               NestedAggregationBuilder nested = AggregationBuilders.nested("attrs_root", "tags");
        NestedAggregationBuilder subAggregation = nested
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("scope_term").field("tags.scope.keyword"));
        subAggregation = subAggregation.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("tag_term").field("tags.tag.keyword"));
        requestBuilder.addAggregation(nested);
        response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Could you please let me know how i can get same results?

Thank Again !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good start, but you just need to add `scope_term` as a sub-aggregation to your nested `attrs_root` aggregation:

```
NestedAggregationBuilder nested = AggregationBuilders.nested("attrs_root", "tags");
TermsAggregationBuilder field = AggregationBuilders.terms("scope_term").field("tags.scope.keyword");
field.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("tag_term").field("tags.tag.keyword"));

// add the next line
nested.subAggregation(field);
```

Comment: Hi Val, How cab i set maximum number of result in same example, and if i want to introduce pagination how is it possible with buckets?

Comment: You can use the size parameter. But if you need pagination, I suggest using the [`composite` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

I found solution as below :

```
 NestedAggregationBuilder nested = AggregationBuilders.nested("attrs_root", "tags");
            TermsAggregationBuilder field = AggregationBuilders.terms("scope_term").field("tags.scope.keyword");
            field.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("tag_term").field("tags.tag.keyword"));

            nested.subAggregation(field);

            requestBuilder.addAggregation(nested);
```